# Why isn't the primary (clustered) key being used in this query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, optimization, execution-plan, query-performance

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 table whose schema structure looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CDSIM_BE]
(
    [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [EquipmentID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SerialNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PyrID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MeasMode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ReadTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SubID] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [ProbePosition] [float] NULL,
    [DataPoint] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_CDSIM_BE] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC, [EquipmentID] ASC, [ReadTime] ASC)
         WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [MonthlyArchiveScheme9]([ReadTime])
) ON [MonthlyArchiveScheme9]([ReadTime])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_CDSIM_BE__SubID_ProbePosition] 
ON [dbo].[CDSIM_BE] ([SubID] ASC, [ProbePosition] ASC)
INCLUDE ([EquipmentID], [ReadTime], [BECorr]) 
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
          SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
          ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [MonthlyArchiveScheme9]([ReadTime])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CDSIM_BE_ProbePosition] 
ON [dbo].[CDSIM_BE] ([ProbePosition] ASC)
INCLUDE ([SerialNumber], [SubID]) 
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
          SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
          ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [MonthlyArchiveScheme9]([ReadTime])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CSDIM_Readtime] 
ON [dbo].[CDSIM_BE]([ReadTime] ASC)
INCLUDE ([EquipmentID]) 
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
          SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
          ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [MonthlyArchiveScheme9]([ReadTime])
```

And I'm executing this simple query:

```
Select Max(Id)
From dbo.CDSIM_BE
```

There are ~2.5B rows in the table.

The query plan shows an index scan being done on the `IX_CdSIM_BE_ProbePosition` index. I'm wondering why SQL Server simply wouldn't use the clustered (and primary) index and immediately go to the last row in the table and retrieve the Id value, since that must be the maximum.

Comment: The *max()* and *min()* aggregates are often problematic in this regards. If you want to be sure an index is used write instead `select top 1 Id from dbo.CDSIM_BE order by Id descending;`

Comment: The clustered index is partitioned on `ReadTime` so it couldn't use the PK as you describe. It would need to find the `Max(Id)` for each partition and then find the max of those. It is possible to rewrite the query to get such a plan as alluded to here though http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/99418/3690

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The clustered index is partitioned on `ReadTime` so it couldn't use the PK as you describe. It would need to find the `Max(Id)` for each partition and then find the max of those. It *is* possible to rewrite the query to get such a plan however.

Using an example based [on the article here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/max-and-min-aggregates-against-partitioned-tables) a possible rewrite might be

```
SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID
FROM   sys.partitions AS P
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID
                    FROM   [dbo].[CDSIM_BE]
                    WHERE  $PARTITION.MonthlyArchiveFunction9(ReadTime) 
                                                    = P.partition_number) AS A
WHERE  P.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.CDSIM_BE')
       AND P.index_id <= 1;
```

To process each partition in turn.

Note the plan still has a scan (with a seek predicate to select the partition) but this is not a full scan of the partition.

The scan is in index order with direction "BACKWARD". The `TOP` iterator can stop requesting rows from the scan after the first one is received.

[image]